# Placing current date inside input value (jsp)

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to add the current date inside the input fields so that the user doesn't always have to enter it.

---

My jsp looks like the following:

[image]

but i want it to look like the following:

[image]

---

I have the following code but it doesn't show the current date:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" width="19%">Start Date :</td>
    <td width="33%" align="left">
        <input type="text" name="bean.dateProperty" value="${fmtDate}"/>
        <fmt:formatDate var="fmtDate" value="${form.bean.dateProperty}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>                      
    </td>
    <td width="15%">End Date :</td>
    <td width="33%">
        <input type="text" value="" id="picker1" name="picker1" alt="Pick a date"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **declare the variable first** and then use it,so your jsp code need to change as below:

```
<fmt:formatDate var="fmtDate" value="${form.bean.dateProperty}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>  
<input type="text" name="bean.dateProperty" value="${fmtDate}" placeholder="${fmtDate}"/>
```

Also need to make sure the value `form.bean.dateProperty` is not empty,if it's empty,you can use below code snippet to declare:

```
<fmt:formatDate var="fmtDate" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the cleanest way to do this, but you can create the date as shown in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_handling_date.htm, you have alot of options in how you format it. Then all you need to do is put that value as the value for the placeholder attribute of your input element. So it could probably look something like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="<%
     Date dNow = new Date( );
     SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
     out.print(ft.format(dNow));
  %>"/>
```